# Use osmdroid in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, osmdroid

Can I use **osmdroid** in a **Titanium Mobile** project?

I need to show an offline map (using something like **MBTiles**) and integrate it with my Titanium project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be possible to wrap osmdroid in a custom module for use in your Titanium project.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-custom-modules